# Sending csv file using Requests.PUT in python [400 Client error: Bad Request]

Tags: python, http, request, put

I am trying to send a csv file using Request module but I keep getting "400 Client Error: BAD REQUEST for url" error. According to the specification that I have, here is an example that was given for curl;
`curl -X PUT -H "Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=ABC.csv" -H "Content-Type: application/csv" -T ABC.csv http://.../api/dss/sites/1/vardefs`

Below is my python code;

```
import requests
filepath = 'C:\...\ABC.csv'
with open(filepath) as WA:
    mydata = WA.read()
    response = requests.put('http://...../api/dss/sites/1/vardefs',
                           data=mydata,                         
                           headers = {'content-type':'application/csv', 'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;filename=Cu_temp.csv'},              
                           params={'file': filepath}
            )
    response.raise_for_status()
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Url target different App data way. So where server script path(its not a url) ? And you try access  without session ? Maybe server work with session.

Comment: @dsgdfg: Sorry, I did not get you. Could you please explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

From 'requests' docs:

> data -- (optional) Dictionary, bytes, or file-like object to send in
>   the body of the Request.

Try sending `WA` directly (without reading first) for a streaming upload instead. Also, it is always recommended to open files in 'rb' (read binary) mode when uploading with requests.

(Edit in response to a comment)

Something like this:

```
import requests

filepath = 'C:\...\ABC.csv'
with open(filepath, 'rb') as WA:
    response = requests.put('http://...../api/dss/sites/1/vardefs',
                            data=WA,
                            headers = {
                                           'content-type':'application/csv',
                                           'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;filename=Cu_temp.csv'
                                      })
```

Does it work this time?

Comment: @R Bazhenov: you mean just like this `filepath = 'C:\...\ABC.json'

response = requests.put(.../api/dss/sites/2/vardefs',
                        headers = {'content-type':'application/json', 'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;filename=Cu_temp.json'},
                        params={'file': filepath})`

Comment: @muhammadwaseem please try the edited version. I removed `params` - there were none in your original `curl` request (as it seems to me), passed `WA` to `data` instead of `mydata` (`mydata` was a string but `data` parameter should not accept strings) and added binary read mode to the `open` statement.

Comment: @ R Bazhenov: Unfortunately, this did not work as well. :(